# Liquid alternative to alcohol to lower density of water

Tags: water, polymers, liquids

I am trying to create a suspension of polypropylene particles in a water based liquid. I want the density of the liquid to be more than or equal to the density of polypropylene (855 - 946 kg/m3) so that the particles don't float or sink too easily. It doesn't have to precisely match, just be close. I had thought of using alcohol, but the problem there is that I need to house the suspension in a container made from either acrylic or polycarbonate, which are both not very resistant to alcohols.

What I'm trying to find is a safe and hopefully cheap liquid that can lower the density of water but not attack acrylic or polycarbonate.

Thanks

Comment: You mean less or equal. Or more or less equal? ;) Depending on the *actual* density of your polypropylene (.85 to .95 is quite a large margin), you get away with an ethanol concentration that doesnt harm your housing.

Comment: As you need decreasing of density, the only reasonable way is using organic solvents miscible with water, with alcohols being the least evil. I suppose methanol may be less aggressive, being closer to water, if health safety is not an issue. Alcohol-water mixtures will be much less aggressive than pure alcohols. Try long term testing of plastic sample with intended liquid. I probably would not like using 25% w/w ammonia with density 0.91 g/ccm. SE also https://www.organicdivision.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/organic_solvents.html